# Other way to implement Casecading dropdown in SharePoint Foundation 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, dropdown, cascading

I need to implement cascading drop-down for Region, State and City. There are more than 20 records so that simple cascading drop-down box does not work. Therefore, I need to implement it with the help of Complex Cascading drop-down. So i try to find another way to implement that type of functionality.

Please help...

Answer (score -1):

Try this for you droppdown casecading

```
var sCamlQuery = "";

// Cascade definition for State dropdown
$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    relationshipList: "States",
    relationshipListParentColumn: "Region",
    relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
    relationshipListSortColumn: "Title",
    parentColumn: "Region",
    childColumn: "State" 
    completefunc: function() {
        sCamlQuery = "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text'>" + $("select[title='Region'] option:selected").text() + "</Value></Eq>";
    })
});

// Cascade definition for City dropdown
$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    relationshipList: "Cities",
    relationshipListParentColumn: "State",
    relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
    parentColumn: "State",
    childColumn: "City",
    CAMLQuery: sCamlQuery
});
```